# How can i achieve this in android with proper clicks?(encircled in the image)

Tags: android

I am making cart of an e-com application. While implementing the cart items i want to show a particular Layout like this. I Have implemented the row, the thing at which i stuck is, The increment (+) and decrement (-) Layout's to make them look similar as in the image. I am not able to decide how to do this,
          I have tried and implemented two different imageviews but didnt work i want the same layout as in the image.
          Can anybody help me out with this?
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: I think you can achive this by using a horizontal linear layout as the base layout for row and use the layout weight property to adjust them . for the three buttons you can again use a horizontal linear layout as the third child of the base linearlayout,

Answer (score 0):

You can use two button for '-' and '+' with selector layout, then u will be able to design exactly as needed. use text view for middle , update textview number in onclick method of those buttons.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: 1. use similar image as you given as button background image for '-' n '+'
2. apply selector drawable for each button (search net about button selector in android)
3. apply onclick method to increase or decrease the value and set the text in textview

Answer (score 0):

Try this code which i have written for my application and its working

```
 mIncrement.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                qtyCount++;
                mQuantity.setText("" + qtyCount);
         }

    });


    mDecrement.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (qtyCount > 1) {                  
                qtyCount--;
                mQuantity.setText("" + qtyCount);

            }
        }
    });
```

Where mIncrement and mDecrement are textview. and mQuantity is the center textView which will increment and decrement on click of + and - respectively

Comment: i am done with the functionality. What i am looking for is the layout. By the way thanks.

Comment: i will edit the post with layout so that it will help you

Comment: i have a layout which is squarer if you want to create a ovalshape layout you need to set raidus for the textview to set radius u can create a new xml file in drawable and set raids accordingly

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do , It's tricky little bit .just use this one at your encircle area ::

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="3"
android:background="@drawable/your custom background" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#ff0000" >
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:background="#00ff00">
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#0000ff" >
</LinearLayout>
```

Here your custom background contains + , - ,and oval shape as per your requirement.
Now you can directly access click event of that 3 linear layout . Got it !!!